# Close linearly independent sequence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

X is an infinite-dimensional normed space. Show that there is a linearly independent sequence ${x_n}$ in X, such that for any sequence ${\epsilon_n} > 0 $ for all n, there is a sequence ${y_n}$ with $||y_n-x_n|| < \epsilon_n$ for all n, such that ${y_n}$ is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose any linearly independent sequence $z_1$, $z_2$, $\dots$, and normalize it so that $||z_i||=1$ for all $i$.  Then, set
$$
x_1:=z_1, \ \ x_{j+1}:=z_1+\frac 1j z_{j+1} \ \ (j=1, 2, \dots)
$$
Since the $z_j$s are linearly independent, the $x_j$s are as well.  For any $j$, changing $x_1$ from $z_1$ to $z_1+\frac 1j z_{j+1}$ will make the sequence linearly dependent as its first element will then equal its $(j+1)$st element.  Since
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty} ||\frac 1j z_{j+1}|| = \lim_{j\to\infty} \frac 1j=0,
$$
the size of the perturbation can be made as small as desired by choosing $j$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Made it look a bit deceptively simple, eh?

Comment: Probably I should come up with this example. Anyway thank you for your help!