# Operator norm converging to 0 for certain condition

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed space and $T_n : X \to X$ a sequence of linear operators such that $\lim_nT_nx = 0$ for all $x$ in $X$. Prove that $\lim_n\|T_n\|=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we must understand that the sequence $(\|T_n\|)$ is bounded by, say, $C$, since this sequence of operators is pointwise bounded (Banach-Steinhaus theorem, here we use the fact that finite dimensional normed spaces are necessarily complete). Now, assume that the claim $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|T_n\|=0$ is not true, then for some subsequence (which I still denote by $(T_n)$) we have $\|T_n x_n\| \geq \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon$ (each $x_n$ is of norm $1$). By compactness (here we use the fact that the dimension is finite once again), we may assume that $(x_n)$ converges to some $x$ (after passing to further subsequence). We can now use triangle inequality to conclude
$$ \|T_n x_n\| \leq \|T_n (x-x_n)\| + \|T_n x\| \leq C \|x_n -x\| + \|T_n x\|$$
and both terms converge to $0$, so we are done.

EDIT
Here comes much better solution. Let $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ be a basis of $X$. We have $T_n x = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k T_n e_k \leq \|(x_k)\|_2 \cdot \|(T_n e_k)\|_2$. Since all norms on finite dimesional space are equivalent this is less than $M \|x\|_X \cdot \|(T_n e_k)\|_2$ for some constant $M$ (dependent on dimension). This means that $\|T_n\| \leq M \|(T_n e_k)\|_2$ and this tends to $0$ from assumptions. Essentially, we just say that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with any norm converges iff its coordinates converge in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By "compactness" you mean "locally compact" right?

Comment: I meant compactness of the unit ball. I also added another solution.

Comment: It seems that my edit coincides with Davide Giraudo's answer.

Comment: Thanks, nice! Also, I hope I'm not rude but I've got another question if you want to see :P  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325702/close-linearly-independent-sequence

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** given $N$ the dimension and $\{v_1,\dots,v_N\}$ a basis, we can assume that the norm is given by $\left\lVert \sum_{j=1}^Na_jv_j\right\rVert:=\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant N}|a_j|$. Then if $x=\sum_{j=1}^Na_jv_j$ is in the unit ball, then 
$$\lVert T_n(x)\rVert\leqslant \max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant N}\lVert T_n(v_j)\rVert.$$